# Method returning bufferdimage for blackjack program

Tags: java, eclipse, image, blackjack

I been trying to make a blackjack program for a school assignment but I have gotten stuck with my method which takes a random number and extracts a picture with it and adds a one to an array which I use to make sure that there can not be two of the same card. However my problem lies in that I want to return the image in the if statement but it does not allow me to, I have to have it outside as well and if the statement is not true it returns null which I want to avoid and instead make it rerun the method until a picture which is not taken gets selected. Im thankful for any help,

```
public static BufferedImage ImportCards() {
    String FileLocation;
    Double Number;
    Number = GetRandom(53);

    int i = Number.intValue();
    String num = String.valueOf(i);
    String main = "DeckOfCards2//Card";
    String end = ".png";

    BufferedImage image = null;

    if (myArray[i] == 0) {
        myArray[i] = 1;
        playerValue = i;
        System.out.println("PLayerValue" + playerValue);
        FileLocation = main + num + end;
        File file = new File(FileLocation);

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return image;
    } else {
        ImportCards();
    }

    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you call same method recursively? Is this an assignment? if not, this is a very bad practice. Why do you need an image precisely? you can print the value into the console as 10♥ or smth like it. Would be much easier to implement.
 More over, why do you read the string of card value? The best approach is to have Card class that defines suit and value instead of reading the 
String num = String.valueOf(i);

Better practice with no recursion:

```
while (image == null ){
   image = importCards();
}
```

but if you insist on using recursion, assign the result of the method to a variable:

```
 }else {

    image = ImportCards();

    }
    return image;
```